# How to receive data passed by the server on client side

Tags: node.js, express

I want to pass data from the server to the client (GET request), when I was using `pug` I did it with

```
// Server:
res.render('pageToRender', { variableToPass: value })
```

And on the client side I just referred to it with `variableToPass`. How can I do this with html and javascript though? I cannot find out...

Comment: your description is bad, can you provide more context

Comment: You answered your own question. Send it from the server like that and use a templating engine like `pug` or `ejs` to get the value. Or do you mean somethhing else?

Comment: With an ajax call maybe ?

Comment: Well I am quite new to Node, I've learned some pug at school but I want to write my app using html. In order to do so I need to pass data acquied by the server back to the client and I don't know ho to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via hack by inlining string value of javascript variable in a template

Here the example:

*template.pug*

```html
<p>Forbes's Pug source code!</p>
<script>
    var variableToPass = JSON.parse('#{variableToPass}')
    console.log(variableToPass)
</script>
```

*server.js*

```js
res.render('pageToRender', { variableToPass: JSON.stringify(value) })
```